# conditions are evaluated upside down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code to validate a form before submitting. This is not the first time i use this code but this is the first time with boostrap.

This is the first time I have noticed that the conditions are evaluated from the last to the first: so if I try to post an empty form I'll have an error for the last field; then once fixed that error it'll move to the previous one and so on back to the top.

My JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tipo = <?php echo $tipo; ?>;
    var error = 0;
    if ($('#screen_name').val()=='') {
        $('#message').removeClass().addClass('text-danger').html("<strong><?php echo _("Inserisci il nome della schermata per proseguire."); ?></strong>").fadeTo(900,1);
        $('#screen_name').focus();
        error = error + 1;
    }
    if (tipo==1||tipo==2||tipo==3) {
        if ($('#scroll_text').val()=='') {
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('text-danger').html("<strong><?php echo _("Inserisci una testo da fare scorrere per proseguire."); ?></strong>").fadeTo(900,1);
            $('#scroll_text').focus();
            error = error + 1;
        }
    }
    if (tipo==2||tipo==4) {
        if ($('#templ_img').val()=='') {
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('text-danger').html("<strong><?php echo _("Scegli una immagine per proseguire."); ?></strong>").fadeTo(900,1);
            $('#templ_img').focus();
            error = error + 1;
        }
    }
    if (tipo==3||tipo==5) {
        if ($('#templ_film').val()=='') {
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('text-danger').html("<strong><?php echo _("Scegli un video per proseguire."); ?></strong>").fadeTo(900,1);
            $('#templ_film').focus();
            error = error + 1;
        }
    }
    if (error==0) {
        ajaxSubmit();
    }
});
```

What am I missing? What is wrong in this code? Assume `tipo=2` and it will evaluate:

1. `#templ_img`
2. `#scroll_text`
3. `#screen_name`

but should be:

1. `#screen_name`
2. `#scroll_text`
3. `#templ_img`

that is both the sequence in the form and in the js code.

Comment: Sure you don't want an `elseif`? With only `if`s you always have a chance of a latter overriding what an earlier had done.

Comment: @Yoshi you are right. each of them this way overwrite the previous one so I see only the last one. Thanks, this solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Yoshi advice I solved the issue by wrapping each if statement checking if the previous one was not in error already.

```
if (error==0) {
    if (tipo==1||tipo==2||tipo==3) {
        if ($('#scroll_text').val()=='') {
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('text-danger').html("<strong><?php echo _("Inserisci una testo da fare scorrere per proseguire."); ?></strong>").fadeTo(900,1);
            $('#scroll_text').focus();
            error = error + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

for example. 
My code was overwriting each error found with the following one. `Else If` is not applicable since the else is for the inner if but I'm first checking `tipo` value.